# How to make facebook app authorization popup show in overlay on facebook page

Tags: facebook, permissions, overlay

there is exactly what I saw.
http://www.facebook.com/cocacola?sk=app_192765884109675
I don't know how they did it. I tried fb.ui change the display options. It always just give me a pop up window. so how to do the overlay?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use redirects as described in the facebook documentation. javascript library will allays result in popup

Answer (score 0):

Finally answer is: 
All you need ask authorization:

```
FB.ui({ method: "permissions.request" });
```

from: 
http://www.facebook.com/mypage?sk=app_1234567890
voila: you have popup in iframe.

However from:
http://apps.facebook.com/myapp
you will have popup without iframe