# Facebook Authorization in popup

Tags: facebook

I have this link:

```
> 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=fc_ID&redirect_uri=http://page.com/c_fb.php&popup=confirm&scope=email&display=popup"
```

Why Authorization window opens in the same window?
I wish open this windows in popup, I add "display=popup" - but no work.

Answer (score 0):

it would be great if you supply screen-shots or more description about your question.
However this Q&A may serve to your question:
[How to make facebook app authorization popup show in overlay on facebook page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835566/how-to-make-facebook-app-authorization-popup-show-in-overlay-on-facebook-page/7343528#7343528)